# Probability: Using Chebyshev and probability yields different answers

Tags: probability

> We have a hotel with three rooms which is opened from April to November, 244 days. Last year, there were 0 occupied rooms on 31 days, 1 occupied room on 22 days, 2 occupied rooms on 107 days and 3 occupied rooms on 84 days.
>
> The mother of the owner wants to visit the owner, and will only do that if the hotel has zero occupants. Find the 90% confidence interval for the amount of days she has to wait before she can visit, once using Chebyshev's inequality and once using a probability distribution.

So using Chebyshev, we have $1-\dfrac{1}{k^2} = 0.9$, we also have $\mu=2$ and $\sigma \approx 1.7 $, so I got an interval $[-3.4..., 7.4..]
$  which I interpreted as the interval $[0,8]$ days.

Now using a probability distribution, I used a geometric one, so $p(y) = q^{y-1}p$ with $p(y) =0.9, q= 160/244, p=84/244$, which gives us $y \approx 4.2$.

Why do these answer vary so wildly and am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The Chebyshev inequality is called inequality for a reason

Comment: Analysing my answer I realise there must be a mistake, 4.2 is too small of a number.

Answer (score 1):

Chebyshev is an upper bound, so your probability estimate will be more precise.